# outputting text whilst a long mysql statement is running

Tags: php, mysql, output

I'm trying to get output buffering to work but the page just sits with the original contents untill it has finished executing...

file1.php<

```
<html>
<body>

      <form action="importscript.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>File: <input type="file" name="import" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Import" /></p>
      </form>
</body>
```

which posts to...

importscript.php<

```
<?php
   ob_start();
   set_time_limit(0);

   $lines = get contents of file that was submitted - about 50,000 lines on average

   echo "Importing - " . count($lines) . " rows<br />"; //I want to show this data
   ob_flush();

$sql = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO data (date,time,duration)
VALUES(:date,:time,:duration);
SQL;

   $sth = $db->prepare($sql);

   $sth->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $sth->bindParam(':time', $time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $sth->bindParam(':duration', $duration, PDO::PARAM_STR);

   $execution_time = microtime();


   foreach ($lines as $line) {

      $lin                = str_replace('"','',$line);
      $parts              = explode(',',$lin);
      $parts[0]           = str_replace('/', '-', $parts[0]);
      $counter++;

      $date              =  $parts[0];
      $time              =  $parts[1];
      $duration          =  $parts[2];

      $ex = $sth->execute();
   }

   $execution_time = microtime() - $execution_time;
   $execution_time = sprintf('It took %.5f sec', $execution_time);

   echo 'Query Finished.  ' . $execution_time' . '<br /><a href="file1.php/">RESET</a>';
   ob_flush(); //output this
?>
```

I've trimmed the script down a lot but you can see where I want to show some data. The script takes on average about 5mins but the browser just keeps on spinning as if the script is still running.

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: You have a syntax error in you last line: Is it just in this code example or in your real code?
`$execution_time'`.

Comment: You should use Ajax, and post the form in the web-page.

Comment: You can output your text (if possible in your case) and then execute the sql with a php call by an image tag <img src="sql.php">. This at least would work over all other cache/flush alternatives.

Comment: @tobias-kun yeah it will be just as I copied, the script works fine apart from the output and timeouts

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a "Split query solution". 
That means that you start with a query that only effects the first 1000 rows of the query..
Once that script is done it automatically redirects to a script that does row 1000 to 2000 and so on until all rows are completed.
This way you give the user constant feedback on the operation and the "spinning Wheel" issue is gone.

Its not pretty but its simple and it works. It solved the problem for me in cases of very long running scripts where output to the user was needed.